# how can i create materialized view with psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, timescaledb

I'm getting an error on creating continuous aggregates with timescaledb which uses postgres materialized views:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URI)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(
     """CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW quotes_1h WITH
    (timescaledb.continuous)
    AS
    SELECT ticker, time_bucket('1h', time) as hour,
    min(close) as low,
    max(close) as high,
    first(close, time) as open,
    last(close, time) as close
    FROM quotes
    GROUP BY
    ticker, time_bucket('1h', time);""")
connection.commit()
```

the error:
psycopg2.errors.ActiveSqlTransaction: CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ... WITH DATA cannot run inside a transaction block

I have set the auto-commit on but it didn't help

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Also the query string is not correct. This part `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW quotes_1h WITH`.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a continuous aggregate and materializing it in the same transaction is currently not supported in TimescaleDB. Thus there are two choices:

1. Don't create a transaction by setting isolation level to [ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT) as answered in another reply.
2. Don't materialize the continuous aggregate by specifying `WITH NO DATA` and [refreshing separately](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#refresh_continuous_aggregate) or through a [policy](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#add_continuous_aggregate_policy).

The second case will be:

```
cursor.execute(
     """CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW quotes_1h WITH
    (timescaledb.continuous)
    AS
    SELECT ticker, time_bucket('1h', time) as hour,
    min(close) as low,
    max(close) as high,
    first(close, time) as open,
    last(close, time) as close
    FROM quotes
    GROUP BY
    ticker, time_bucket('1h', time)
    WITH NO DATA;""")
```

Comment: hi @k_rus is there an issue on the timescaledb github about this? I ran into this issue and I found my answer here on stack overflow...

Comment: @Jeff I don't know if the issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with:

```
from psycopg2.extensions import ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
connection.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

Comment: This still didn't work for me with the latest psycopg2, TimescaleDB, and PostgreSQL versions as of June 22, 2021